# Indexable anchor links

Tags: seo, url, links, anchor

I have seen that anchor links can not be indexed since the crawlers read `www.example.com/page#someanchor` as `www.example.com/page`.

It is the web browser that then interprets the anchors to jump in the appropriate section or open an accordion (my case).

I would like to know if there is currently a way to have a url with this structure indexed by search engines:

**`www.mysite.com/somepage?modal=foo#foo`**

The site contains multiples accordions, each anchor link opening each associated accordion.

Comment: [this post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86369/setting-up-site-links-for-a-one-page-scrolling-site-can-anchored-links-be-used) has a good answer to this issue

Answer (score 2):

Found some answers in this blog post, http://blog.analytics-toolkit.com/2014/virtual-pageviews-google-analytics-why-how-when

Explaining ways to achieve it with virtual pages.

But I think that means we can track the tabs/accordions that are clicked in Google Analytics, making these virtual pages indexable is another story.